# Haskell -- any way to qualify or disambiguate record names?

Tags: haskell, record

I have two data types, which are used for **hastache** templates. It makes sense in my code to have two different types, both with a field named "name". This, of course, causes a conflict. It seems that there's a mechanism to disambiguate any calls to "name", but the actual definition causes problems. Is there any workaround, say letting the record field name be qualified?

```
data DeviceArray = DeviceArray
    { name :: String,
      bytes :: Int }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

data TemplateParams = TemplateParams
    { arrays :: [DeviceArray],
      input :: DeviceArray }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

data MakefileParams = MakefileParams
    { name :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)
```

i.e. if the fields are now used in code, they will be "DeviceArray.name" and "MakefileParams.name"?

Comment: There's [this](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/Haskell/records.html), although it's a bit old... I wonder if anyone knows what the status of the "better records proposal" is?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As already noted, this isn't directly possible, but I'd like to say a couple things about proposed solutions:

If the two fields are *clearly distinct*, you'll want to always know which you're using anyway. By "clearly distinct" here I mean that there would never be a circumstance where it would make sense to do the same thing with either field. Given this, excess disambiguity isn't really unwelcome, so you'd want either *qualified imports* as the standard approach, or the *field disambiguation* extension if that's more to your taste. Or, as a very simplistic (and slightly ugly) option, just manually prefix the fields, e.g. `deviceArrayName` instead of just `name`.

If the two fields are in some sense *the same thing*, it makes sense to be able to treat them in a homogeneous way; ideally you could write a function polymorphic in choice of `name` field. In this case, one option is using a *type class* for "named things", with functions that let you access the `name` field on any appropriate type. A major downside here, besides a proliferation of trivial type constraints and possible headaches from the Dreaded Monomorphism Restriction, is that you also lose the ability to use the record syntax, which begins to defeat the whole point.

The other major option for similar fields, which I didn't see suggested yet, is to extract the `name` field out into a single parameterized type, e.g. `data Named a = Named { name :: String, item :: a }`. [GHC itself uses this approach for source locations in syntax trees](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/ghc/SrcLoc.html#t:Located), and while it doesn't use record syntax the idea is the same. The downside here is that if you have a `Named DeviceArray`, accessing the `bytes` field now requires going through two layers of records. If you want to update the `bytes` field with a function, you're stuck with something like this:

```
addBytes b na = na { item = (item na) { bytes = b + bytes (item na) } }
```

Ugh. There are ways to mitigate the issue a bit, but they're still not idea, to my mind. Cases like this are why I don't like record syntax in general. So, as a final option, some *Template Haskell* magic and [the `fclabels` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/fclabels):

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Control.Category
import Data.Record.Label

data Named a = Named 
    { _name :: String, 
      _namedItem :: a }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

data DeviceArray = DeviceArray { _bytes :: Int }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

data MakefileParams = MakefileParams { _makefileParams :: [MakeParam] }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

data MakeParam = MakeParam { paramText :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

$(mkLabels [''Named, ''DeviceArray, ''MakefileParams, ''MakeParam])
```

Don't mind the `MakeParam` business, I just needed a field on there to do something with. Anyway, now you can modify fields like this:

```
addBytes b = modL (namedItem >>> bytes) (b +)
nubParams = modL (namedItem >>> makefileParams) nub
```

You could also name `bytes` something like `bytesInternal` and then export an accessor `bytes = namedItem >>> bytesInternal` if you like.

Comment: That looks like a very nice solution in general, but I don't think it will work for my particular case: hastache uses the Data.Generics "reflection", so I want the actual field names to be "name". Perhaps this question is related to the more general issue of having some sort of "union" record type, i.e. avoiding the "item" field you mention above.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: You can use whatever field name you like. If it's called `name`, fclabels will generate a lens named `lName` instead. The underscore is just nicer if you're only using the lens. You'd still have the annoyance of nested records, which will make things in hastache uglier. As an aside, this is a great example of why I'm wary of reflection-based techniques; magic non-local dependencies on irrelevant syntax makes code fragile and non-compositional.

Comment: @gatoatigrado: Also, the general issue you're thinking of basically ends up leading to some sort of structural subtyping.  It's a nice idea, but my impression is that implementing it well is quite tricky.

Comment: Should be noted that this answer is now out of date. The GHC extension `-XDuplicateRecordFields` achieves exactly what OP was asking for as of GHC 8.0 (and I think some earlier versions).

Answer (score 6):

What you can do is to put each data type in its own module, then you can used qualified imports to disambiguate.  It's a little clunky, but it works.

Answer (score 5):

Record field names are in the same scope as the data type, so you cannot do this directly.

The common ways to work around this is to either add prefixes to the field names, e.g. `daName`, `mpName`, or put them in separate modules which you then `import qualified`.

Answer (score 4):

There are several [GHC extensions](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#disambiguate-fields) which may help. The linked one is applicable in your case.

Or, you could refactor your code and use typeclasses for the common fields in records. Or, you should *manually* prefix each record selector with a prefix.

Comment: Sorry I did not make an explicit reference in the question; I was already aware of that one, unfortunately it only clears up references to the same field names from different data types in different modules, whereas I'm concerned with _defining_ two in the same module.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the name in both, you can use a Class that define the name funcion. E.g:

```
Class Named a where
    name :: a -> String

data DeviceArray = DeviceArray
    { deviceArrayName :: String,
      bytes :: Int }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

instance Named DeviceArray where
    name = deviceArrayName

data MakefileParams = MakefileParams
    { makefileParamsName :: String }
    deriving (Eq, Show, Data, Typeable)

instance Named MakefileParams where
    name = makefileParamsName
```

And then you can use `name` on both classes.